# Bundler failed to fetch json 1.6.5

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to bundle gems for my app in production machine and it consistently failed today with this error message:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: too many connection resets (http://cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org/gems/json-1.6.5.gem)
```

Is there any reason that bundle is trying to fetch from a down mirror rather than the main website? I can still download the gem file from `http://rubygems.org/gems/json-1.6.5.gem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rubygems.org redirects that request. It has nothing to do with bundler.

```
$ wget  http://rubygems.org/gems/json-1.6.5.gem
--2012-05-08 00:09:44--  http://rubygems.org/gems/json-1.6.5.gem
Resolving rubygems.org... 204.232.149.26, 204.232.149.25
Connecting to rubygems.org|204.232.149.26|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org/gems/json-1.6.5.gem [following]
--2012-05-08 00:09:44--  http://cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org/gems/json-1.6.5.gem
Resolving cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org... 205.234.175.175
Connecting to cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org|205.234.175.175|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 424960 (415K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `json-1.6.5.gem'

100%[======================================>] 424,960     2.38M/s   in 0.2s    

2012-05-08 00:09:45 (2.38 MB/s) - `json-1.6.5.gem' saved [424960/424960]
```

Comment: It's funny: I'm from Vietnam and when I try to download, I get this: ` 3% [======>      ] 13,340      --.-K/s  eta 25m 37s`. The download is never finished. Login into a server in US and I can download in no time (as you did above).

Comment: Hmm.. restarting my routers fixes the problem. Kinda weird. thanks for the answer.